# Apache RewriteRule and Skipping Logic

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've pretty much hit a wall here.  As far as I can tell, this should work, but it doesn't.

I have a local development address with a wildcard subdomain of *.localhost, and friendly URLs of /[0-9]/somestring.  What I am trying to do is have `username.localhost/1/page` to `localhost?pageId=1&username=username`.  The complication comes in trying to get both the home page at username.localhost as well as the individual pages i.e. username.localhost/1/page to both work.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\,\.]+$ - [S=1]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.localhost
RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.php?username=%1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\,\.]+$ index.php?pageId=$1&username=%1
```

With /1/page pages, the first rule meant to skip matches and skips, but fails to rewrite correctly.  However, if I remove the first 2 rules, it'll rewrite /1/page pages just fine.

It's as if it's not skipping, yet if i change it to S=2, it skips both rules.  Argh.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, it actually *is* doing what you expect it to do. Only, after it does that, it has a second go at your rule set, which messes things up. What's happening looks more specifically like this:

- Request to `http://username.localhost/1/page` is made
- The input `1/page` matches the first rule, `S=1` is applied
- The input `1/page` matches the third rule, URL is rewritten to `index.php?pageId=1&username=username`
- An internal redirection is performed by `mod_rewrite` (all good so far, but...)
- `mod_rewrite` handles the internal redirection, and starts processing the rules again
- The input `index.php` does not match the first rule, `S=1` is not applied
- The input `index.php` matches the second rule, URL is rewritten to `index.php?username=username`
- (the internal redirection occurs again, the same rewrite is performed, but `mod_rewrite` detects the redirection loop and stops processing now)

There are a few different ways to fix this, but I think the easiest one here is to just make sure the file doesn't exist, and then roll the pattern from the last rule into a condition for the previous one:

```
# Make sure we haven't rewritten to a file yet (the "directory" gets processed
# before DirectoryIndex index.php is applied)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Check that the input doesn't match the pattern we want handled later
RewriteCond $0           !^([0-9]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9_,.-]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^([^\.]+)\.localhost
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?username=%1

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9_,.-]+$ index.php?pageId=$1&username=%1
```

**Edit**: The above version also catches things that don't match your page pattern and acts like they were `index.php?username=username`, which might not be desired. The following would avoid that, and is a bit more concise anyway:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^([^\.]+)\.localhost
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?username=%1

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9_,.-]+$ index.php?pageId=$1&username=%1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I can see the logic of how a second run through the rules could throw a wrench in the whole thing.  Sorry if I'm a bit dense, though, but I can't follow how your solution resolves it.  The REQUEST_FILENAME comes out to be index.php which is always going to exist, and consequently trying this doesn't seem to pan out.

Comment: @Zurahn - A request to `http://username.localhost/` will have an initial `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` of `/website/root/dir/`, since there's no request path after the domain. This isn't a file, so the condition `!-f` is true on the first pass. On subsequent passes (in this case because of a `RewriteRule`, but the same would be true if `DirectoryIndex` was applied), the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` becomes `/website/root/dir/index.php`, which is a file, causing the condition to fail and not allowing the first rewrite to be performed again accidentally.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I'll work with what you've provided and think I should be able to manage it.